# Update state with dynamically constructed object using reducers in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reducers

I have an array of values which are set in state to a boolean. I need to loop through the array and set each value to the payload (true). The code below works correctly but I'm looking for a way to achieve the same result for an arbitrary amount.

```
criticals = ["critical-1-524", "critical-4-572", "critical-15-24", "critical-30-48"]

return {
      ...state,
      mapboxToggleLayers: {
        ...state.mapboxToggleLayers,
        [criticals[0]]: action.payload,
        [criticals[1]]: action.payload,
        [criticals[2]]: action.payload,
        [criticals[3]]: action.payload
      }
    }
```

Here is my working version but this deletes all the values in it's state object.

```
return {
  ...state,
  mapboxToggleLayers: {
    ...state.mapboxToggleLayers
    [criticals.map(el => {
      let critObj = {}
      return critObj[`${el}`] = action.payload
    })]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using hooks by the way

Comment: Can you show your state?

Comment: mapboxToggleLayers: {
    "someValue": true
  },

Comment: Arbitrary values will be added to to this state in the same format when they are present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `criticals.map` will return an array. Based on your example, it seems that you need to dynamically create an object. You can use `reduce` with the spread operator:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  mapboxToggleLayers: {
    ...state.mapboxToggleLayers,
    ...criticals.reduce((result, key) => {
      return {...result, [key]: action.payload}
    }, {})
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. My reputations are too low to give you an up vote but thanks for helping and the explanation. it now makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer by clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons.